# Excel Function of looking for the same same email address and compare the value of another corresponding cell

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

i have two sets of worksheets of registration details, names, email, date data is changeed etc.

i want to find if the email address in worksheet A appears in worksheet B and if there is, compare the value of date data is changed in both worksheets and if there is a different, either display a text or conditional formatting.

I'm looking at MS Access with SQL but does not seems to get the result that i want

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

for comparing worksheets, `VLOOKUP` is the function you are going to be using.

the formula would look something like this:
`=VLOOKUP(emailToFind,RangeThatHasEmailAndDate,ColumnOfInfoToReturn,False)`  (false=exact match)

So, with a table that looks like this:

```
Emails                  Dates
example@example.com     1-Jan
example1@example.com    3-Jan
example2@example.com    7-Jan
example3@example.com    2-Jan
example4@example.com    1-Feb
```

then the formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)` in C1 would get the date from the other sheet

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact syntax of Access, it a long time I worked with it, but general SQL is

```
data = SELECT set1.v1, set2.v1, ... FROM set1 join set2 ON set1.email=set2.email;
for item in data
    if item.value[0] == item.value[1]
          do something
    endif
endfor
```

It is just pseudo-code, maybe it helps ...
if you post, what you tried, I probably remember the syntax and can help more in detail